# A log4j2 log can not be output to the file in spring boot2.0, who can help me?

Tags: java, spring-boot

My project has a log module that is implemented using log4j. Before the project's spring boot version is 1.5.8, I recently upgraded it to spring boot2.0 packaged project after the error, according to the online solution, I replaced the log4j log4j2, and then remove the spring boot default logging module The package is successful and the program can run normally. However, there is something wrong with the log module function. It can output the log on the console correctly, but it can't export the log to the file, but not all the log information can't be output to the file. It's OK to output the log to the file in the startup class. Here is the main code of my log module

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Filter;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.api.*;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.impl.BuiltConfiguration;
```

public class LoggerUtil {
    static Logger logger = null;

```
public static void fatal(String message) {
    if (logger != null) {
        logger.fatal(message);
    }
}

public static void debug(String msg) {
    if (logger != null) {
        logger.debug(msg);
    }
}

public static void info(String message) {
    if (logger != null) {
        logger.info(message);
    }
}

public static void warn(String message) {
    if (logger != null) {
        logger.warn(message);
    }
}

public static void error(String message) {
    if (logger != null) {
        logger.error(message);
    }
}

public static void initLogger(String filePrefix, String level) {
    ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();
    builder.setStatusLevel(Level.ERROR);
    builder.setConfigurationName("RollingBuilder");
    // create a console appender
    AppenderComponentBuilder appenderBuilder =
            builder.newAppender("Stdout", "CONSOLE")
                    .addAttribute("target", ConsoleAppender.Target.SYSTEM_OUT)
                    .add(builder.newFilter("ThresholdFilter", Filter.Result.ACCEPT, Filter.Result.DENY)
                            .addAttribute("level", Level.ERROR));
    appenderBuilder.add(builder.newLayout("PatternLayout")
            .addAttribute("pattern", "%d [%t] %-5level: %msg%n%throwable"));
    builder.add(appenderBuilder);
    // create a rolling file appender
    LayoutComponentBuilder layoutBuilder = builder.newLayout("PatternLayout")
            .addAttribute("pattern", "%d [%t] %-5level: %msg%n");
    ComponentBuilder triggeringPolicy = builder.newComponent("Policies")
            .addComponent(builder.newComponent("CronTriggeringPolicy").addAttribute("schedule", "0 0 0 * * ?"));
    appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender("rolling", "RollingFile")
            .addAttribute("filePattern", filePrefix + "-%d{yyyyMMdd}.log")
            .add(layoutBuilder)
            .addComponent(triggeringPolicy);
    builder.add(appenderBuilder);
    // create the new logger
    builder.add(builder.newLogger("Logger", Level.DEBUG)
            .add(builder.newAppenderRef("rolling"))
            .addAttribute("additivity", false));

    builder.add(builder.newRootLogger(getLogLevel(level))
            .add(builder.newAppenderRef("Stdout"))
            .add(builder.newAppenderRef("rolling")));
    LoggerContext ctx = Configurator.initialize(builder.build());
    logger = ctx.getLogger(KnowledgelibapiApplication.class.getName());
}

private static Level getLogLevel(String level) {
    switch (level.toUpperCase()) {
        case "FATAL":
            return Level.FATAL;
        case "DEBUG":
            return Level.DEBUG;
        case "INFO":
            return Level.INFO;
        case "WARN":
            return Level.WARN;
        case "ERROR":
            return Level.ERROR;
        default:
            return Level.WARN;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Solution to output logs to file is create log4j2.xml file under src/main/resources & create the Logger using LogManager in your classes as given below :

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

And then use logger.info or logger.debug or logger.error to output the logs to file.

Sample log4j2.xml file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <!-- Console Appender -->
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss a} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <!-- File Appender -->
        <File name="File" fileName="d:/app.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss a} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </File>

    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <!-- Log everything in custom package -->
        <Logger name="your base package" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="File" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Hope this will helps you...